# iOS - Implement iMessage-like scrolling effect

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to achieve the scrolling effect like `iMessage` in iOS 8+ in any ordinary `UITableView`? 
preferable using Swift
cause it looks so cool...

Comment: Which type of scrolling effect, Can you tell in detail?

Comment: The effect where you scroll and the cells movement are a little bouncy, the space between the cells change as they bounce up and down, you know...

Comment: No I do not know. sorry

Comment: There was a WWDC talk about this. They specifically talked about Messages I believe.

Comment: Is it possible to make a github project and collaboratively Implement this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are looking for is UIKit Dynamics
I was also interested on this some time ago and I refer this link to do it.

https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/collection-views-and-uidynamics/

Comment: interesting, did you ever actually implement it in any UICollectionView?

Comment: I had with both CollectionView and Table view (concept is same) at that time, but I don't have any code with me now, but I remember it worked as expected without a problem. Just see how its done with UICollectionView and try to port it to TableView

Comment: how about making a github project?

Comment: Any Swift example like this?