# UICollectionViewCell Momentum Animation?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a project that has some pretty specific design guidelines. I've been playing around with animations for a while now but I have not come up with exactly what is needed.

I'm trying to mimic the effect of the iOS Messenger app, where when scrolling messages they appear to have some 'momentum' to them. How is this effect accomplished? Also what is it called? I haven't found any info on it so far.

I am trying to implement this effect in Swift.

Comment: just found what I was looking for - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38428926/ios-implement-imessage-like-scrolling-effect

Comment: Do you consider this link to be a solution? If so, consider closing your question. If you're looking for that code in swift, try https://github.com/ronaldwidha/ASHSpringyCollectionView or https://gist.github.com/bgayman/ccab09987129a0f0a723bffbf93fa6c1If you are looking for more information on the topic search of UIKit Dynamics with UICollectionViewLayout.